# How to initialize char array in struct

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, struct, initialization

how to initialize a char array in structure in C# i am doing this

```
struct cell
{
    public char[] domain =new char[16];
    public int[] Peers;
    public int NumberOfPeers;
    public char assignValue;
}
```

but its giving error that we cannot initialize an array in the body of structure! can any one tell the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx) for this. Look at MSDN.

```
struct cell
{
    public cell(int size)
    {
         domain = new char[size];
         this.Peers = Peers;
         this.NumberOfPeers = NumberOfPeers;
         this.assignValue = assignValue;
    }    
}
```

Comment: How can a struct have a parameterless explcit constructor?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yep, you are right. It can't be withour parameters. Updated.

Comment: It looks like you take in an "in" parameter (value parameter) and then immediately assign something new to your parameter. That's confusing. Also remember to assign all fields.

Comment: And now it looks like you're assigning the three last fields to themselves. But that won't compile as you're trying to read unassigned fields.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a constructor

```
struct cell
{
    public cell(int charArraySize) : this()
    {
         domain = new char[arraySize];
    }

    public char[] domain;
    public int[] Peers;
    public int NumberOfPeers;
    public char assignValue;
}
```

Note: Even with structures, you should not have public fields but encapsulate them in properties.

And being able to *change* the values of a *structure* is an even worse problem - [mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

Comment: `struct` objects cannot contain parameterless constructors.

Comment: How can a struct have a parameterless explcit constructor?

Comment: You're correct about the properties but this won't actually compile as per Even and Jeppe's comments.

Comment: This won't compile. An instance constructor of a struct **must** assign all instance fields of the struct. You can "cure" this by actually assigning them, or by "chaining" the (implicit) parameterless constructer, like so: `: this()`

Comment: Now the struct is legal (in the sense that it compiles). But it is still a struct that is **mutable** by design. Actually, the "simple" fields of type `int` and `char` can only be used through mutation of an already created `cell` value. Mutable structs will often lead to errors (especially for people whose knowledge does not suffice to initialize structs, like the original poster). So maybe a warning about mutable structs would be relevant in this the answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: The fact that if the type of `Peers` is an array, then `var thing1 = thing2; thing2.Peers[1]=9;` would either store 9 in `thing1.Peers[1]` or not write anything in `thing2.Peers[1]` is apt to cause much more confusion than would be caused by exposed fields of primitive types.  Actually, I'm not sure how to make something like `thing1.Peers[1]=9;` behave as a value-type array should in C#, though the equivalent can be done in vb.net.

Answer (score 3):

One major limitation of value types in .net is that they cannot contain arrays, even fixed sized ones, unless one leaves the realm of managed code (C# provides a means of including fixed-sized arrays within a value type using the `unsafe` and `fixed` keywords, but code that uses that ability will be unusable in certain security contexts).  They can contain references to arrays, but if a structure that holds an array reference is copied, the copy will receive a reference to the same array as the original.

While would suggest that in most cases it's better for a structure type to be completely open about what it contains (expose its entire state via public fields) than for it to pretend to be anything other than a collection of variables bound together with duct tape, a structure whose state is supposed to encapsulate the state of a mutable class object (such as a `System.Array`) must use a different pattern.

If a struct is supposed to behave as a value-type array of 64 floats, and one wishes to actually have the floats stored within a System.Array rather than in 64 separate fields, the struct should probably contain a private field `Arr` of type `float[]`.  To read element `n`, check whether `Arr` is null.  If so, return zero.  Otherwise, return the value of `Arr[n]`.  To write element `n`, set a temp variable `Arr2` to a new `float[64]` and copy `Arr` if it's not null.  Then set `Arr2[n]` to the desired value, and replace `Arr` with `Arr2`.  Note that at once a `float[]` has been stored to `Arr`, it will again never be written to.  If an attempt is made to write to element 5 of the struct, the struct will receive a new array with the proper value there; element 5 of the old array will be untouched.  Consequently, the struct will behave as a value-type array should (except that writing to it will be much slower than a write to a normal array would be).

If a type will need a large array, it may be better to use a `float[][]` or a `float[][][]`; for example, one might hold 4096 elements using 16 arrays of 16 arrays of 16 arrays of 16 elements.  In that scenario, writing to an element would require generating/copying a `float[16]`, a `float[16][]`, and a `float[16][][]`; the three small arrays of size 16 may be better than two arrays of size 64, and would almost certainly be better than one array of size 4096.

Value-type semantics can certainly be useful, but as noted structures can't provide terribly efficiently if they contain arrays.  An alternative design, if the number of elements is small, would be to simply have a field for each element, and have an indexed property accessor use a switch statement to read or write a struct field.  A little icky, but for structs smaller than a dozen elements or so it would almost certainly be more efficient than using arrays as described above.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and possibly should) use a class instead of a struct (though it makes a difference, but you don't tell how you're going to use your type).

Or you can write a constructor. But note that a struct instance constructor must take in at least one parameter.

If you stick to the struct, be sure to make it an immutable struct. One way of doing this is to make all fields `readonly`, and then assign to them in your instance constructor.

Answer (score 1):

try using something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

public class TCardDB

{

public TCardDB(string strCardNo)

{

CardNo = strCardNo;

FName = LName = string.Empty;

OpenMode = FingerCount = 0;

Finger1 = new string[3];

Finger2 = new string[3];

}

..........

..........

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the first comment of this question
[C# array within a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704161/c-sharp-array-within-a-struct)
Fixed Size Buffers - [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx)
That did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

For char[] specifically;

It's a bit weird we have so much difficulty with an array of characters, when we can easily add a string...
Which is just a char[] anyway...
With all the indexing functionality you need.

This worked for me at any rate.