# why can't we define array in structures in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, managed

Hi all kindly help me to understand why cant we define Arrays in structs in c#

i tried the other asked question but most of them suggests to use class instead of a struct.
that is ok for implementation purpose but i want to understand why can't we define arrays in structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an array in a structure, but that is quite pointless in most cases.

An array is an object, so the structure will only contain a reference for an array. If you create an array and assign to the reference, the array is created on the heap. The usual reason for using a structure is to avoid creating objects on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

You can but you have to initialize the array in all constructors because structs require that you assign values to all members in the constructor(s).

```
 public struct YourStruct
 {
     public char[] arr; 

   public YourStruct(int size)
   {
      arr = new char[size];
   }
 }
```

Like others have mentioned, if you are creating an ARRAY of OBJECTS (not value types) then a struct is not appropriate to begin with.
Look here:  [How to initialize char array in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915321/how-to-initialize-char-array-in-struct)

Comment: i am sorry but, can u please tell me what is wrong with this line of code inside a struct 

public long LongTest = new long[1000];

Comment: shouldn't it be:  public long[] LongTest = new long[1000];

Comment: yeah it is exactely public long[] LongTest = new long[1000];
but i get this error on compile time.
cannot have instance field initializers in structs

Comment: i told you already, you need to initialize the array in the constructor not at the declaration.

Comment: i am really thankful to you for your answer and comments but i requested in my question that i want to know why can't  we do so otherwise i would have used a class instead. [sorry for bothering you].

Comment: i am sorry but i tried to upvote but  it says "needs 15 reputation atleast "unfortunately  that is what i am running out of right now

Comment: i am sorry i am much novice to stackoverflow than the c# so please tell me how to do so .

Comment: my answer should have a check mark to the left, if you click it it should go green.

Comment: i surely will mark it answer, btw is there any chat kind of thing i can have with you about c# questions as i have tons of question

Comment: friend my on facebook, I have a small group of software engineer friends that we post Q&A.   Tom McKeown in florida.  link to the group here:  https://www.facebook.com/groups/flswes/

Comment: Structs are not immutable by specification, though. You should never create a mutable struct but you can do. For example, if you have struct A { int Number; A() { Number = 4 } }, you can still do "A a; a.Number = 6;" and then a.Number will contain 6.

Comment: ok true, they should be immutable, however the properties must be assigned a value upon creation.  I have modified my answer, thank you for that.

Comment: Your code won't compile. A structure can't have an explicit parameterless constructor.